# How to index a pandas dataframe using locations wherever the data changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file whose first column consist of times and whose other columns have other various data. I want to remove all rows where none of the data changes from one time to the next. I attempted to use drop_duplicates, but this removes all duplicate rows (based on every column except the first because then none of the rows would be removed) whereas I also want to keep instances where the data changes back to what a previous row had been. For example, if this was the input:

```
time    |    value A   |   value B
10:30   |       1      |     2    
10:31   |       1      |     2    
10:32   |       2      |     3    
10:33   |       2      |     3    
10:34   |       1      |     3    
10:35   |       1      |     2
```

I want this output:

```
time    |    value A   |   value B
10:30   |       1      |     2      
10:32   |       2      |     3    
10:34   |       1      |     3    
10:35   |       1      |     2
```

However drop dupes would also delete the last row at 10:35 since it has the same value in columns 'value A' and 'value B' as the first line at 10:30. I understand there is most likely no function that can do this alone, so the only solution I have come up with so far is to iteratively use drop_duplicates() on each pair of rows, but this process could be much much slower. I was thinking about using the where() or loc() or mask() functions but can't seem to come up with any better solutions. Is the solution I came up with the best/fastest or are there any faster solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description of your problem, it sounds like you could just specify a subset of columns to consider for duplicates with `subset=`, and indicate you want to keep the *last* value with `keep='last'`.

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep='last', subset=['valueA', 'valueB'])
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df

    time  valueA  valueB
0  10:31       1       2
1  10:32       2       3
2  10:33       2       3
3  10:34       1       3
4  10:35       1       2

>>> df.drop_duplicates(keep='last', subset=['valueA', 'valueB'])

    time  valueA  valueB
2  10:33       2       3
3  10:34       1       3
4  10:35       1       2
```

---

#### Or

If you want to retain *non-consecutive* duplicates (which doesn't match your sample output), you could use [`shift()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with -1 as the shifting period to retain the latter half of consecutive duplicates, or 1 to retain the first half of consecutive duplicates.

```
>>> dfp = df.set_index('time')

>>> dfp[(dfp.shift(-1) != dfp).any(1)]

       valueA  valueB
time                 
10:31       1       2
10:33       2       3
10:34       1       3
10:35       1       2

>>> dfp[(dfp.shift(1) != dfp).any(1)]

       valueA  valueB
time                 
10:31       1       2
10:32       2       3
10:34       1       3
10:35       1       2
```

Comment: ya beat me to it, except I was thinking based on his post it would be `keep='first'` as he wants to delete rows where nothing changed from the first record.

Comment: @MattR _"I want to keep instances where the data changes back to what a previous column had been"_ sounds like "last" to me, and it seems to match  his desired output.

Comment: use of any() instead of conditional is great +1

Comment: I did intend to keep the first row, but also as Mitch said in the solution, I want to "retain non-consecutive duplicates".

Comment: @JoelKatz Then I suppose my second solution is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, except I want to retain the first of a set of consecutive duplicates. So would I use positive 1 as the shifting period instead?

Comment: @JoelKatz Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JoelKatz also, I notice you've never marked an answer as accepted - you can mark whatever answer you found the most helpful as "accepted" with the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shift instead of drop_duplicates to remove only consecutive duplicates

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val1': [1,1,2,2,1,1], 'val2': [2,2,3,3,3,2]})

df.loc[(df.val1.shift(1) != df.val1) | (df.val2.shift(1) != df.val2)]


    val1    val2
0   1       2
2   2       3
4   1       3
5   1       2
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that :

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
    time  valueA  valueB
0  10:30       1       2
1  10:31       1       2
2  10:32       2       3
3  10:33       2       3
4  10:34       1       3
5  10:35       1       2

In [10]: compose=df.filter(like='val')

In [11]: good = (compose != compose.shift()).any(1)

In [12]: df[good]
Out[12]: 
    time  valueA  valueB
0  10:30       1       2
2  10:32       2       3
4  10:34       1       3
5  10:35       1       2
```